# Extract specific text from PDF - iText

Tags: java, pdf, text, itext

I am currently reading a page from PDF file. I would always like to extract specific text from the page. Can I do this easily if I know the internal structure of the PDF? If yes, how? Below is what I have:

```
public  void read(PdfReader reader) throws IOException{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1));
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    System.out.println("Text Line: " + sb.toString().substring(43,47));

}
```

The line

```
System.out.println("Text Line: " + sb.toString().substring(43,47));
```

is what I am concerned about. Is there a better way to do things other than using substring?

Text Extract from PDF:

```
SUPPLEMENT # :
1
RC :
2
D  :
0
R :
2
W: TOTAL :
0 0
```

Comment: You want to *to extract specific text*. How exactly is this *specific text* specified? Is it the only text to be found in a rectangle given by fixed coordinates? Is it the only text using a given font or color? Is it the text following a unique other label text? For all this there are solutions in case of well-behaved PDFs but you have to be more specific, currently the question is too broad.

Comment: Edited the post to add the text extract from pdf. Now, I'd like to read the values after RC: and D: always.

Comment: In that case I'd search for "RC :", "D  :", and "R :" in that string and select the text respectively in-between.